# Is wheat bad for animals?

Tags: talmud-gemara, food, rashi, animals

Rashi on [Bava Metzia 90a](https://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=22&daf=90&format=pdf) D"H UMatrezes (a few lines from the bottom) says that if an ox has a certain stomach disease, wheat worsens the ox's condition.

However, the Gemara says on [Bava Kamma 20a](https://www.sefaria.org/Bava_Kamma.20a.16?lang=bi)  that wheat is always bad for cows.

Which is it? Is wheat always bad for animals, or only when they are sick?

Comment: Maybe it's like alcohol with medication

Comment: If cattle are fed wheat it needs to be introduced into their diet gradually to allow their stomachs time to adjust to processing it.  The gemara in Bava Kamma could be talking about giving large amounts of wheat to cattle that are not used to it. Rashi in BM could be saying that even if an ox is used to wheat, this is counter indicated if it now has a stomach condition.

Comment: It might depend on whether they have IBS and need a low FODMAP diet